# Sorting queryset results in a template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have the following model:

```
class TestCase(models.Model):
    tc_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    tc_title = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class TestSteps(models.Model):
    ts_case = models.ForeignKey(TestCase, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ts_seq_no = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    ts_instruction = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I want to display a test case together with its associated test steps in the template. For this I have written two views, one is not so nice but works:

```
def tc_steps(request, pk):
    case = TestCase.objects.filter(id=pk)
    steps = TestSteps.objects.filter(ts_case_id=pk).order_by('ts_seq_no')
    context = {'case': case, 'steps': steps}
    return render(request, 'testman/tc_steps.html', context)
```

Not very nice because I have to retrieve two querysets. Better to have this one:

```
def tc_steps(request, pk):
    case = TestCase.objects.filter(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'testman/tc_steps.html', {'case': case})
```

because this contains all the information I need in the template. Now the problem:

In the template for the second view I use the following tag to display the test steps:

```
{% for step in case.first.teststeps_set.all %}
```

Which works but the steps aren't in the right order. In the template for the first view I just use:

```
{% for step in steps %}
```

And get the correct order (sorted by ts_seq_no) because I did the sorting in the view already. I tried to use a filter but couldn't find one that does what I want. My question is, is there any way to do an order_by in the template tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a method to the TestCase model to return its related steps in the required order.

```
class TestCase(models.Model):
    ...
    def ordered_steps(self):
        return self.teststeps_set.order_by('ts_seq_no')
```

Now in the template you can do `{% for step in case.first.ordered_steps %}`.

Comment: I like it. While it's more code, it's more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [dictsort](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-dictsort) like this(use [dictsortreversed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#dictsortreversed) for reversed order):

```
{% for step in case.first.teststeps_set.all|dictsort:"ts_seq_no" %}
```

Comment: It works, but I like the other guy's solution better ;)